# How to download the template page including css, js and associated images using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been given a webpage/website and asked to write SCRIPT for:

1. Using the given website as template, any user must be able to create websites of same layout. 
        - These sites will have similar header, nav, content area and footer, but background image, header color, navigation text, etc.
   must be editable.(USING SCRIPT)
        - Store it locally on the system
2. When I click download button, how to download all the associated files (html,css, js, image files)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for GNU [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/).

Comment: May be not. General users don't have ftp access.

Comment: I don't think you need FTP access in this case. If your website is, say, http://www.google.com, then `wget -E -H -k -K -p http://www.google.com` will get all of the files.